# Accessing a Character Pointer in a Structure Array

Tags: c

I have an array of pointers to structs that each have a char pointer that is pointing to a string. I want to compare this word to another word.

I compile my code but get this error:request for member word in something not a structure or union. on this line:

```
strcmp(mytable[i].word, word) == 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the definition of mytable?

Comment: mytable is an array of pointers to structures.

Comment: Then change `mytable[i].word` to `mytable[i]->word` (and update the question -- an "array of structs" is not the same thing as an "array of pointers to structs")

Comment: Right okay. What does that change exactly do?

Comment: It changes from trying to access the member `word` of a pointer to accessing the member `word` of the pointed-to struct.

Comment: Hey. I have some of the pointers in this array nulled. If I want to copy the contents from one pointer (not in the array) to one in the array that is nulled, will there be a problem?

Comment: Before you can copy the contents, you have to make the array element point to something that you can copy into, by calling `malloc()`. Or you can simply copy the other pointer into the array element, so it points to the same structure.

Comment: I think you need to go back to your books and study more about using pointers in C. This is not a productive way to learn basic programming techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you commented, mytable is an array of pointers to structures, then instead of:

```
mytable[i].word
```

You should have:

```
mytable[i]->word
```